# Having very odd results printing a nested loop

Tags: python, loops

I have the following code:

```
def printBoard(bd, userX, userY):
    board = [[0]*(col+2)]*(row+2)
    for i in range(col + 2):
        for j in range(row + 2):
            print(i, " ", j)
            if((i==0 and j==0) or (i==0 and j==row) or (i==col and j==0) or (i==col and j==row)):
                board[i][j] = "+"
            elif(i==0 or i==col):
                board[i][j] = "-"
            elif(j==0 or j==row):
                board[i][j] = "|"
            else:
                board[i][j] = getBoard(j-1, i-1, bd, userX, userY)

    print('\n'.join(map(''.join, board)))
```

I'm looking for this result:

```
+----------+
|..........|
|..........|
|..........|
|........10|
|........1*|
+----------+
```

But I always get this:

```
+----------+
+----------+
+----------+
+----------+
+----------+
+----------+
+----------+
+----------+
+----------+
+----------+
+----------+
```

I know that the last line works fine, I have used it before. I think the problems are in the if statements but I don't understand why they are behaving like this. I apologize if I did anything wrong posting, it's my first time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect points in your output when you never print any?  What does `getBoard` do?

Comment: Postingc `getBoard` will be helpful. I'm assuming, as `col` and `row` are not being passed to `printBoard`, they are global variables. Any possibility that they are changing through the loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `[[0]*(col+2)]*(row+2)` you get a list containing `row+2` instances of the same list. Because they are instances of the same list, modifying one results in them all being modified. So your output is the last line of the board, since those are the last modifications.

See this transcript:

```
>>> row, col = 10, 5
>>> board = [[0]*(col+2)]*(row+2)
>>> board[1][1] = 42
>>> board
[[0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Note that element 1 has changed on *every* row even though only `board[1][1]` was updated.

Correct is to write:

```
board = [([0] * (col+2)) for _ in range(row+2)]
```

Or equivalently but more consistently:

```
board = [[0 for _ in range(col+2)] for _ in range(row+2)]
```